# jQuery disable the previous span and the next span, on click span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble applying class to the previous element or the next element.

[image]

```
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up up"></span>
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down down"></span>
```

I want to disable the second span, when I click the first span and vice versa.

```
$(document).on('click','.up, .down',function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('up')){
        var down = $(this).parent().nextAll('a.comment-vote-down');
        down.removeClass('disable-link').addClass('disable-link');
    }else if($(this).hasClass('down')){
        var up = $(this).parent().prevAll('a.comment-vote-up');
        up.removeClass('disable-link').addClass('disable-link');
    }
});
```

[example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnovq390/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xnovq390/2/ Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to find class `.comment-vote-down` that doesn't exist in your HTML code

https://jsfiddle.net/xnovq390/4/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.up, .down',function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('up')){
            var down = $(".down");
            down.removeClass('disable-link').addClass('disable-link');
        }else if($(this).hasClass('down')){
            var up = $(".up");
            up.removeClass('disable-link').addClass('disable-link');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have an a with a class of .comment-vote-down, or comment-vote-up.

Either take that part out of your nextAll selection:

```
.nextAll('a');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xnovq390/1/

or, add in the class to your HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="comment-vote-up">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xnovq390/3/

Answer (score 0):

If the `.up` element is always the previous element from the `.down` one, you can simply do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.up, .down', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('up')) $(this).next().addClass('disable-link');
    else $(this).prev().addClass('disable-link');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).on('click','.up, .down',function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('up')){
            $(this).addClass('disable-link');
            $('span.down').removeClass('disable-link');

        }else if($(this).hasClass('down')){
            $(this).addClass('disable-link');
            $('span.up').removeClass('disable-link');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers already stated, there is no <s>spoon</s> element with `.comment-vote-down` class.
But additionally to make life easier, you could buffer the 2 elements, bind the click to them and disable the ones not clicked, reducing the code to

```
var btns = $('.up, .down');
btns.click(function(){
    btns.not(this).addClass('disable-link');
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnovq390/6/)

If you'd want to disable the containing `a`, the 'other's parent could be obtained by chaining parent() : `btns.not(this).parent().addClass('disable-link');` ( or `.closest('a')` if there is a deeper hierarchy)